# NOTHING works to prevent screen locking while watching videos

Tags: release-freya, applications, display

I checked every tutorial, checked every solution on this web site and i am so disappointed to say that there is no built in solution or addon to prevent system from locking or suspending. So my question is why is that? I see this trend in every linux distro, but at least at some of them caffeine works, which is pathetic solution to start of. That said, hats off to Caffeine developer/s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine-plus
```

It works fine on Freya.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this again. It actually works. I installed it today, but removed right away because i did not like idea of cluttered top bar. Is there anyway to hide app indicator?

Comment: Heres the thing. I don't want for end user to wonder what is cup of cofe doing in his indicator and to actually brake it and then call me and say that laptop is shutting down.